# Trying to get the Xsd2Code .net class generator from XSD schema Codeplex utility to work

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, xml-serialization

I installed [Xsd2Code version 3.4](http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/) mentioned in [the StackOverflow posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886031/visual-studio-2010-xml-xsd-schema-to-classes-within-the-ide) and I don't see the "run Xsd2Code Generation" menu option when I right click on an xsd file in my solution. I also checked to see if this worked in my VS2008 installation, no luck. I then installed version 3.4 and tried the beta version. What gives? Am I doing something wrong?

Edit: Links corrected.sorry

[image]
[image]

Comment: it works on my other PC. Must be some kind of conflict. I tried to turn off all of my extensions and add ins, but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same promlem. After some experimens I have found an one way to resolve it.
Click on Tools->Customize->Commands. Now choose menu type and click on Add Command. Find the Addins->"run Xsd2Code Generation" item. It's all.